# iOS - Passbook Registration Url For Automatic Updates

Tags: php, ios, passbook

I am having quiet a few problems implementing the automatic update functionality on a pass of passbook. But my current question is (It is not a very good one, I dont have alot of knowledge about web end work so forgive me if I ask something obvious or stupid). 
I am using this url against the key `webServiceURL` in the `pass.json` file.

```
https://serverURL/v1/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passIdentifierAsIsPastedFromJsonFile/serialNumAsIsPastedFromJsonFile
```

Now, according to my understanding and things I read on the stackoverflow and apple documentation. `deviceLibraryIdentifier` is supposed to be added by iOS itself and will be sent to server in a `POST` request. So, we are to fetch 3 values from URL, 1 from header and 1 from json payload/body. I just wanted to confirm if I am doing these things correctly ? (Because server end person is saying that he is getting `deviceLibraryIdentifier` as is, as a string "deviceLibraryIdentifier" and he is not getting any key for `authenticationToken` in the header also). Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `webServiceURL` in `pass.json` should simply be `https://serverURL`.  The device will automatically complete the rest of the URI before each request.  You need to implement a RESTful service that will be able to parse the string, recognise which of the 5 methods of the PassKit WebService is being requested, and then respond with the correct response, [as per the spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988).

So in the case of a registration, the device will take your server URL, add `/v1/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}` to the URL to complete the URI.

Your server should then parse the URI, identify the pass via the `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` provided and create a record in your devices database that corresponds to the `deviceLibrayIdentifier` and the `devicePushToken` that will be contained in a JSON object in the body of the request.

To help developers get started, Apple provide a [Ruby and SQLite](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip) sample that you could either just directly implement, or could port to PHP.

Comment: Oh so that was the problem I was having , placing the whole URL in the webServiceURL key in pass.json. Thank you very much, and thank you for giving the sample for Ruby and Sqlite, I did not encounter that before. Appreciated.

Comment: For me it called GET endpoint, not POST.. absurd